# postgresql return error : ERROR: canceling statement due to user request

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.6,it's ok to execute in psql command:

```
  select pg_cancel_backend(a.pid)  from pg_locks a join pg_class b on a.relation = b.oid join pg_stat_activity c on a.pid = c.pid where c.datname = 'mydb' and a.mode like '%AccessShareLock%';
```

However, it prompts an error : **"ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request"** when I execute the following scripts:

```
/app/postgres/pgsql/bin/psql -h "127.0.0.1" -p 6661 -U "postgres" -d "mydb" -tc "select pg_cancel_backend(a.pid)  from pg_locks a
> join pg_class b on a.relation = b.oid
> join pg_stat_activity c on a.pid = c.pid
> where c.datname = 'mydb' and a.mode like '%AccessShareLock%';"
```

what is the difference between this two methods?

[image]

Comment: probably，it requires some privilege or auth to execute it in shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods execute the same statement, so the end result is the same. However when you use the psql command, you can execute directly from the shell. The first command requires that you are already connected to postgres.